# How to get the list of child nodes from firebase Realtime database using RestClient in unity c#

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, rest-client

I using RestClient API to get data from the firebase Realtime database. I want to get the count of the children of the "data" node. And also want to download the complete data node. how to do this using RestClient API

[image]

Comment: SO is for help with existing code; attempt to write some code and when you get stuck post it and your troubleshooting and we'll take a look. Asking us to provide the code is off-topic for SO - we are not a code writing service. Please attempt the code and update the question with it.